# how to use sensitivity list in multiple processes that are dependent

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm writing a code for a simple arithmetic equation d=1+(k*o). I have three processes in my code.the third process is dependent on second and second is dependent on first.I'm unable to keep the sensitivity list correct. The output goes undefined.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity dcalc is
    Port ( k : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           o : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           e : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           d : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
              clk: in  STD_LOGIC);
end dcalc;

architecture Behavioral of dcalc is
COMPONENT divd
    PORT(
         d1 : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         e : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         remi : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         clk : IN  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;
signal  endp1,d2,k1,o1,e1,d3: unsigned (7 downto 0);
--signal d3:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

--process 1
process(k,o,e)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
k1<=unsigned(k);
o1<=unsigned(o);
e1<=unsigned(e);
endp1<=x"01";
end if;
end process; 

--process 2
process(endp1)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
d2<=1+(k1*o1);
end if;
end process;

--process 3
process(d2)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
d<=std_logic_vector(d2);
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

In the first process, conversion is done. When process 1 is done then the d2 should be calculated in process 2. when d2 is calculated in process 2, d should be updated in the process 3. here is my testbench code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY ccalctb IS
END ccalctb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF ccalctb IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT dcalc
    PORT(
         k : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         o : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         e : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         d : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         clk : IN  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal k : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal o : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal e : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal d : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: dcalc PORT MAP (
          k => k,
          o => o,
          e => e,
          d => d,
          clk => clk
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  
k<=x"07";
o<=x"08";
e<=x"07";
      wait for clk_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Please help.
Here is the simulation result after changing all the process sensitivity list to only clk:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a synchronous (clocked) process, the sensitivity list is required to be only the clock (and possibly asynchronous reset):

```
process(clk)
begin
  if RISING_EDGE(clk) then
    k1<=unsigned(k);
    o1<=unsigned(o);
    e1<=unsigned(e);
    endp1<=x"01";
  end if;
end process;
```

With your original sensitivity list, changes on the D flip-flop (or register which is a vector of D flip-flops) inputs triggered process execution, but as we know the output doesn't change immediately, it waits for the clock edge.  And then when the clock edge came, `clk` wasn't in the sensitivity list, so the simulation ignored it.  As a result, your outputs never update in simulation.

(In contrast, synthesis tends to ignore your sensitivity list and just place a logic element configured as a genuine D flip-flop, which will update properly on the clock edge)

Comment: I have changed the sensitivity list to only clk. But still the output remain undefined. Can you please help with other two process sensitivity list?

Comment: @soulz: They are all synchronous processes.  So they all have the same sensitivity list, `clk`.  Does your simulator show you the value of intermediate signals?  After making the change to the first process, you should start seeing that `k1`, `o1`, `e1` change even if the final output doesn't.

Comment: I have changed all the process sensitivity list to clk. Yes it shows the intermediate signals.Still the output remains undefined. k1,o1,e1 remains undefined.

Comment: How long are you running the simulation?  You need to go to approximately 140ns or later.  Are you seeing the clock edges you expect?  And the input changes you expect?

Comment: @soulz: Did you stop the simulator, recompile with the code changes, then load and run the simulation again?  What software are you using?

Comment: After the clk changes to 1 there is no simulation output. Im using xilinx 14.7 isim. No clk is not changing as expected and inputs remains 0.

Comment: 5ns is the last. I cant go any further. There is no simulation after 5ns.

Comment: The clock is controlled by the testbench.  Are you simulating the right module?  Because `dcalc` has a clock too, but it never causes it to change, the change has to come from outside.

Comment: @soulz Are you getting an error at 5ns?  You can always keep going unless you encountered a fatal error.  If there is an error, what's the attached message?

Comment: Yes sir. I am simulating the right module. But clk never cahnges.

Comment: Oh, just saw your screenshot.  Your question about sensitivity lists was totally different from the problem you are having.  Right now your multiplier `k1*o1` is (8x8) and has a 16-bit output.  You can't store all 16 bits into `d2`.

Comment: @soulz In fact, this should not have made it past the analysis and elaboration stages to let you start running the simulation.  Didn't you get any errors or warnings during elaboration?

Comment: Yes sir. Now i saw the error. Thanks a lot for your patience. Error was popping up during simulation. So i never noticed it. Thanks a lot sir

Comment: I got the output. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @soulz: You're welcome, and good luck as you continue learning VHDL.  It's a very powerful approach and a lot of fun.

Comment: There was no error during check syntax. And i cant check synthesis because its not my top module.

Comment: "

In a synchronous (clocked) process, the sensitivity list is required to be only the clock (and possibly asynchronous reset)..." This is semantically incorrect English. The sensitivity list can contain any signal evaluated in an expression in the process (including `clk`). Because all other evaluations are within an if statement in sequential statements controlled by a condition (an expression) evaluating `clk`, they are not needed here. They are legal here. See IEEE Sttd 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement and 10.2 Wait statement.

Comment: The idea of paring down sensitivity lists (as opposed to the list generated with the reserved word **all**) is to reduce processing overhead when simulating. Interesting enough that would only entail evaluating the if statement condition and re-execute the implicit wait statement evaluating the sensitivity list when the if statement condition is not valid. Barely more effort than not resuming execution at all. (Processes are resumed in the same wait statement they are suspended executing.)

Comment: @user1155120: Other signals are syntactically legal here, but will not get the job done.  If you want correct simulation on ALL simulators (most of which do not follow the specification 100%), the sensitivity list should be exactly as I have stated.

Comment: @BenVoigt having more signals on the sensitivity list for a clock process doesn't change the results. It causes only more process activations. There is no simulator known to me that produces false results on the behavior you describe.

Comment: @Paebbels: I think I've encountered toolchains where it royally disrupts synthesis , and simulator bugs are a dime-a-dozen (the behavior exhibited in this question is a bug in my mind, there is no way elaboration should be able to take place without discovering that bus width mismatch).  There is nothing to gain from false triggers of a process, only potential downsides.

Comment: The requirement for matching elements between an assignment target and a right hand expression are testing during execution.  Mismatched 'bus widths' show up during synthesis after elaboration. For signals see IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7 Execution of a model, 14.3.7.4 Signal update para 1 "For a composite signal R, an implicit subtype conversion is performed to the subtype of R; for each element of R, there shall be a matching element in both the driving and the effective value, and vice versa.". And that should be semantically legal not syntactically legal above.

Comment: @user1155120: Elaboration is when bus widths are checked; you can't infer the sizes of open-ended arrays except by processing the generic and port mappings of instantiations. I certainly have used simulators which infer and check all array sizes prior to the first time tick of simulation. You have your semantics and syntax backwards above -- the bus width mismatch is syntactically legal but semantically illegal. Oh, you were "correcting" my comment about the sensitivity list? But I meant what I wrote, unrelated signals in the list are syntactically legal and semantically worse-than-useless.

Comment: Your view on simulator behavior doesn't match the standard (-1987 thru -2002, 12.6 Execution of a model,12.6.2 Propagation of signal values. -2008, 14.3.7.4 Signal update). Scalar subelements of composites have separate drivers requiring matching elements. A waveform element on the right hand side of an assignment contains a value expression is not required to be static. Dynamically elaborated function calls don't return a value of a static subtype in most cases. There's no way to check matching elements using a host's link editor when elaboration is separate from execution.

Comment: Matching elements can be checked during **analysis** with locally static subtypes for both the right hand expression and target (e.g. `k1<=unsigned(k);` type conversion is a basic operation). Permission is implied in (-2008) 9.4 Static expressions (see term *locally static subtype*). There's low demand for a course on how to implement VHDL - there are probably around 30 people world wide actively involved in implementation or maintenance. Those implementing all tend to make the same mistakes.

Comment: @user1155120: I've only ever been interested in the synthesizable subset, this is in the synthesizable subset, it has static `d1'RANGE`, `o1'RANGE`, `k1'RANGE`, and the compatibility can and should be statically checked.  Finding and reporting errors as early as possible is a quality-of-implementation issue.  Not finding the error until an edge appears on the assignment input is a poor implementation.

Comment: It's simply not possible to find a matching element mismatch for non-locally static subtypes until simulation. It's not as your opinion purports *poor implementation*.

Comment: @user1155120: That is of no concern here, because in the code discussed there are no non-static subtypes.

Comment: Yes, with the exception you keep making blanket statements that aren't accurate.